# Firebase database stopped working after a sign in

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I created a new Unity project with very simple 2 methods :

```
public class FirebaseScripts : MonoBehaviour {

    public void One()
    {
        FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance.SetEditorDatabaseUrl("https://xxxxx.firebaseio.com/");

        FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.RootReference.Child("test").SetValueAsync("TEST").ContinueWith( task => {
            Debug.Log(task.IsCanceled + " " + task.IsCompleted + " " + task.IsFaulted);
        });
    }

    public void Two()
    {
        FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance.SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync("xxx@xxx.com","test").ContinueWith( task => {
            Debug.Log(task.IsCanceled + " " + task.IsCompleted + " " + task.IsFaulted);
            Debug.Log(task.Result.Email);
        });
    }

}
```

The security settings on the database is **public**, meaning it can be read or write by anyone.

When calling `One()` sure enough it prints `False True False` and when I look in the Firebase console it did shows a new record.

After calling `One()` I can call `Two()` to login and it returns `False True False` too. Indicating a successful login. And I can also call `One()` as many time as I want.

However, if I call `Two()` first it still returns `False True False` but now `One()` stopped working. After calling `One()`, a warning will appear in fixed interval :

> 01/02/0001 17:42:30 [Warn] PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Provided
>   authentication credentials are invalid. This usually indicates your
>   FirebaseApp instance was not initialized correctly. Make sure your
>   database URL is correct and that your service account is for the
>   correct project and is authorized to access it.

And I can never get a response from the method `One()` again. (Until I exit the play mode and enter again, which clears the login session) Why this is happening? And why must I "warm up" Firebase with `One()` first for the login to not causing problem?

SDK version is 4.0.2.